# R: how to display a table with a heat map-type representation of percentage values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

R: how to display a table with a heat map-type representation of percentage values, as in Excel. same as displayed in SC.

In heat-map table/plot, I want all columns shown below except ***Total(%)***, with conditional formatting such that lower values are displayed in green while higher values are displayed in red.

The ***0 or early(%)*** column should not be highlighted in heat map.
Check attached screenshot of excel to understand what I am looking for.
I am unable to understand what to do in this type of excel to R conversion.

In database displayed below columns in table.

```
User        0 or early(%)    <=5(%)      <=10(%)     <=15(%)     <=20(%)     <=25(%)    TOTAL (%)

A               57              15          18          5           5           0         100           
B               64              22          12          2           0           0         100
C               73              12          10          3           2           0         100
D               45              37          7           4           3           5         100
E               87              4           2           2           1           4         100
F               44              39          3           0           1           13        100
G               84              7           2           5           2           0         100
H               90              3           0           7           0           0         100
I               88              2           2           7           2           0         100
J               43              17          0           34          6           0         100
K               69              4           2           20          2           2         100
L               37              5           5           0           5           49        100
M               69              18          0           10          3           0         100
N               59              8           3           30          0           0         100
O               91              6           3           0           0           0         100
P               50              7           10          27          3           3         100
Q               40              23          7           13          10          7         100
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to get the same heatmap than hose displayed by excel in `ggplot2` or in `plotly` ? What code have you try ?

Comment: @dc37 I have tried to develop it from row data provided in excel for understanding now we get data in sql and here all data are separated, while in excel there is only two columns, so i used `rpivotTable(inventory,
  aggregatorName = "Count",
  cols =  "Days_Bin",
  rows = "User",
  rendererName = "Heatmap",
  width = "100%",
  height = "500px")` In Excel there was only on column for days_bin now in SQL get columns by separate  bins percentage.

Comment: Sorry, it's not really clear what your data looks like. Have you try to import your data into R ? What they look like ? Can you post the return of `dput(NameOfYourDataframe)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reproduce the same "heatmap" than the one you obtained with excel, I will rather consider using `formattable` package instead of `ggplot2`. `formattable` allow to make data frames to be rendered as HTML table with formatter functions applied, which resembles conditional formatting in Microsoft Excel (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html).

I inspired from @MrFlick's answer on this post: [Is it possible to use more than 2 colors in the color_tile function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885176/is-it-possible-to-use-more-than-2-colors-in-the-color-tile-function) to build the following answer.

First, we are creating a function that will make the color pattern for the heatmap. Based on your excel output, 0% values are green and then you have a gradient from yellow to orange to red.

```r
library(formattable)
color_tile2 <- function (...) {
  formatter("span", style = function(x) {
    style(display = "block",
          padding = "0 4px", 
          `border-radius` = "4px", 
          `background-color` = ifelse(x ==0, "green", csscolor(matrix(as.integer(colorRamp(...)(normalize(as.numeric(x)))), 
                                               byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(c("red","green","blue"), NULL), nrow=3))))

  },
  x ~ percent(x/100))}
```

Here, applying the function made below to the dataframe and getting particular columns colored and other not:

```r
library(formattable)
formattable(df, align = "c", list(
  area(col = `<=5(%)`:`<=25(%)`) ~color_tile2(c("yellow","orange","red")),
  User = FALSE,
  `TOTAL_(%)` = FALSE,
  `0_or_early(%)` = formatter("span", style = ~style(color = "darkgreen"), x ~ percent(x/100)))
  )
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to get ?

**Reproducible example**

```r
structure(list(User = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q"), `0_or_early(%)` = c(57L, 
64L, 73L, 45L, 87L, 44L, 84L, 90L, 88L, 43L, 69L, 37L, 69L, 59L, 
91L, 50L, 40L), `<=5(%)` = c(15L, 22L, 12L, 37L, 4L, 39L, 7L, 
3L, 2L, 17L, 4L, 5L, 18L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 23L), `<=10(%)` = c(18L, 
12L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 
7L), `<=15(%)` = c(5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 34L, 20L, 
0L, 10L, 30L, 0L, 27L, 13L), `<=20(%)` = c(5L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 10L), `<=25(%)` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
7L), `TOTAL_(%)` = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Yes, this is the exactly same as expected, you are genius. I was totally confused how to do this, thanks a lot for the help & explanations.

Comment: You're welcome ;) Glad it satisfy you even if it is not using `ggplot2`.